# jinja template remove whitespace

Tags: templates, jinja2

I'm using jinja to do some code generation, the template is like this:

```
enum MsgType
{
{% for type in types -%}
{% for member in type.members -%}
    {% if member.is_enum -%}{{ member.value }},{% endif -%}
{% endfor -%}
{% endfor %}
};
```

It generate code like this:

```
enum MsgType
{
Login,Data,
};
```

If I don't use the '-' in template, it includes a lot of whitespace lines, but how can I generate like this:

```
enum MsgType
{
    Login,
    Data,
}
```

Comment: I have removed the C++ tag.  You may be generating C++ code with Jinja, but C++ is irrelevant within the context of this question.  Your template could be generating Javascript, Lua, SmallTalk, Assembly or Russian and the problem would be identical.

Comment: right, thanks @paddy